# Appium python switch to webview Timed out after 15525ms waiting for the root AccessibilityNodeInfo in the active window

Tags: python, selenium, appium

```
    ...
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@text='xxx']").click()
    self.dc['noReset'] = True  
    self.dc['appPackage'] = "com.tencent.mm"
    self.dc['appActivity'] = ".ui.LauncherUI"
    self.dc['platformName'] = 'Android'
    self.dc['deviceName'] = 'M2010J19SC'
    self.dc['chromeOptions'] = {'androidProcess': 'com.tencent.mm:tools'}
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", self.dc)
    ...   
    print("1 ", driver.contexts)
    print("1 ", driver.current_context)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("2 ", driver.contexts)
    print("2 ", driver.current_context)
    driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW_com.tencent.mm:tools')
    print("3 ", driver.contexts)
    print("3 ", driver.current_context)
    ...
```

print log is:

```
1  ['NATIVE_APP']
1  NATIVE_APP
2  ['NATIVE_APP', 'WEBVIEW_com.tencent.mm:tools']
2  NATIVE_APP
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception: Timed out after 15525ms waiting for the root AccessibilityNodeInfo in the active window. Make sure the active window is not constantly hogging the main UI thread (e.g. the application is being idle long enough), so the accessibility manager could do its work.
why can not switch to 'WEBVIEW_com.tencent.mm:tools' ? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue, appium working with old version WeChat 7.0.12, but now tencent blocks the old version wechat login.